# Recognizing a returning visitor in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

If an anonymous user on a site returns multiple times in a certain period (lets say three times a week), then I need to suggest the user to log in/register on the site.

I was thinking about keeping this info in a cookie, but is there a better way of doing this? Or maybe a standardized way build in .NET or in a third party library?

Comment: Think Occams Razor, there are many ways of achieving what you want to do, however are they easier or any better than simply using cookies, most likely not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For anonymous user the only way is the cookie.**

You place an encrypted ID to the cookie and connect that id with your **anonymous user** on the database.

Google set up advertising cookies to last for 30 days for example

http://www.google.com/privacy/ads/

Google analytic set up up to 2 years

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/concepts/gaConceptsCookies.html

> Google Analytics sets an expiration date of 2 years for unique visitor
>   tracking. However, if your visitors delete their cookies and revisit
>   your site, then Google Analytics will set new cookies (including new
>   unique visitor cookies) for those visitors. While you can configure
>   the duration of a user session cookie (from the default 30 minutes)
>   using the _setSessionCookieTimeout() method, you cannot configure the
>   duration of the unique visitor cookie.

Comment: What if the the computer belong to an internet cafe and used by 10s or 100s of different users?

Comment: @nuux in general all this data are statistical, they do not need to be accurate 100%. From the other hand you need to be sure that are not comming from bot, or other sources that change the results. We have see this time to time, data that come from bot, and our routing is not calculate them correct and give wrong results, and we fix the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways, but they not 100% accurate. That said, a cookie would be adequate for your situation.

One other way is that you can check the and store the visitor's IP address combined with the UserAgent value. This might not be entirely accurate since sometimes a company could have lots of internal users, but using only one public IP address.

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Javascript and [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage) to display the information.

```
if (localStorage.getItem('lastVisit')) {
    alert('You have been here before!');
} else {
    localStorage.setItem('lastVisit', new Date());
}
```

Comment: No, maybe not in every browser but it´s still an option.

Comment: This is apparently only supported in HTML5. Looks great and easy, but I need it to work in every browser. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

In short, just use a cookie, there isn't anything wrong with this method. Also, this allows the user to clear such information from their system and is the expected behavior of a website from an end-user, so its good practice.

Also quickly, a 'Visitor' is generally defined as a visit from a unique address (eg. IP Address). So you would want to check the IP to consider it as the same visitor. If they visit the website from a different IP, that would be considered a second visitor which is also expected behavior. You could go a bit further here though, and check the browser and consider that a separate visitor, or other specific information that would be available through all web browsers.

Conclusion, just use a cookie and IP Address, try not to over-complicate it, and definitely don't choose an option that isn't cross-browser if you don't go the cookie/IP route.

Hope this helped.